# How does Alexa's conversation flow work?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I want to write a quiz/interview game where the flow is like this:

> "Alexa, start Movie Trivia."
>
> *Welcome to Movie Trivia. Do you need to hear the rules?*
>
> "No."
>
> *What category would you like to play? Comedy, drama, or animation?*
>
> "Comedy."
>
> *Question 1. In what year was Star Wars released? A, 1970. B, 1977. C, 1980.*
>
> "B."
>
> *Correct. Your score is 1. Question 2...*

I managed to write spaghetti code to accomplish this, with lots of `if session.attributes.category`, `if session.attributes.needsRules`, etc stuff, 3 pages of nested if-elsing.

I'm using Node and the official Alexa SDK, so I read its documentation cover to cover, but it's quite confusing and broken in places (examples that haven't worked since June, instructions for old UIs and so on). My question is: what kind of flow is 'correct'/traditional for something like this?

In the code I was writing, I used `elicitSlot` a lot, which is nice because it lets me listen solely for the things I expect to hear (eg `answerType` "A", "B", "C"). But `elicitSlot` leads to you re-triggering the same intent. So would it be a matter of having each intent check if a slot is filled, and if not, speak a question and elicit that slot, and if so, set a session attribute and then forward to a different intent?

That seems sloppy. Maybe the solution is to define an `askingRulesState`, `askingCategoryState`, `askingQuestionState`, etc, each with only a single handler. But states with only a single handler seems... wrong?

If I'm going to ask the user a question like "What category would you like to play?", does that mean I need to create a `SetCategoryIntent`? And if so, how would I prevent the user from triggering that intent except when I want them to?

I realise this is a bit of a big vague question but it's really difficult for me to boil it down to something smaller and clearer, since my issue is that the flow in general is really disorienting to me. I'd appreciate even the smallest tip!

Answer (score 0):

You might have a look [here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#dialog-interface), this will handle a lot of the if else's and elicit slots you wrote. For the questions and such you wil indeed probably have to make a state so you  can check if you are in question asking state or just in the set-up state. This will help your skill deter men what it has to do. (don't forget to ALWAYS put this state back in because Alexa is tricky if you do not do this sometimes. You can find more info over [here](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs#skill-state-management). This also looks like a pretty good example of what you are trying to make.
Hope this helps you forward a bit.